# What does perpendicular to the plane of paper signify?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am getting confused with the term.. Magnetic field acting perpendicular to the plane of paper.,.. Does it means that field is into the plane of paper or outside it.?

Comment: It could mean either of the two. Unless specified, consider any one without loss of generality. Perhaps you can provide more information so we get the context?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether the current producing the magnetic field is flowing anti-clockwise in the plane of the paper or clockwise. The magnetic field will come out of the paper towards you if the current is anti-clockwise and away from you if the current is clockwise. This assumes you are looking at the plane of the paper at right angles from above.